# Keep original structure of dataframe after groupBy in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a large csv with some social media data:

```
message_id, user_id, message, date
"1", "123", "some message blah blah", "Sun May 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013"
"2", "123", "another message blah", "Sun June 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013"
"3", "123", "i want this message removed", "Sun June 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013"
"4", "321", "more blah", "Mon June 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013"
```

and want to remove messages based on some criteria within a group (for this example the group can be `user_id`.

This is what I've done: created a standard function for my exclusion criteria, defined a `udf` based on this method and then apply the function to the grouped data:

```
def exclusion_criteria(data_list):
    keep = []
    for d in data_list:
        if some_condition:
            keep.append(d)
    return keep

myUdf = udf(exclusion_criteria, ArrayType(StringType()))

msgsDF = session.read.csv("data.csv", header=False)
filterMsgsDF = msgsDF.groupBy("user_id").agg(collect_list("message")
    .alias("message")).withColumn("message",myUdf("message"))
```

In the end I get something that looks like:

```
filterMsgsDF.take(1)
[Row(user_id='123', _c2=['some message blah blah', 'another message blah'])]
```

but the issues is that I'm dropping information associated with each message (`message_id` and `date`). What I want in the end is something like

```
["1", "123", "some message blah blah", "Sun May 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013"]
["2", "123", "another message blah", "Sun June 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013"]
["4", "321", "more blah", "Mon June 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013"]
```

**Is there a way to join this other information or keep it during the groupBy / agg step?** Maybe `groupBy` isn't the best way to do this?

Comment: Just append the other information about message in same list. I.e messageId, message, date will be single list.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Where am I appending the other information?

Comment: [Row(user_id='123', _c2=[[123,'some message blah blah',date],[124, 'another message blah',date]])]

Comment: Somewhat like what I described above. If you still don't get it let me know I will answer, if that is the result you are looking for.

Comment: I understand what you are describing but I'm not seeing how to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
filterMsgsDF = msgsDF.withColumn('message_list', collect_list(msgsDF['message']).over(Window.partitionBy('user_id')))
```

Output:

```
+----------+-------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|message_id|user_id|message                    |date                           |message_list                                                               |
+----------+-------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1         |123    |some message blah blah     |Sun May 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013 |[some message blah blah, another message blah, i want this message removed]|
|2         |123    |another message blah       |Sun June 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013|[some message blah blah, another message blah, i want this message removed]|
|3         |123    |i want this message removed|Sun June 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013|[some message blah blah, another message blah, i want this message removed]|
|4         |321    |more blah                  |Mon June 12 15:08:58 +0000 2013|[more blah]                                                                |
+----------+-------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```